# How to view Word/Excel files in read-only mode in Xamarin

Tags: c#, excel, xamarin, ms-word, readonly

We have a cross-platform app written in native Xamarin. Recently we've got a requirement to retrieve Word/Excel files from server, store them locally and display in read-only mode. There is a problem that when files are opened by third-party applications, they can be edited. One of ideas was to convert files to html files, but we didn't found appropriate and free library for that solution. Maybe somebody knows how to view Excel and Word files in read-only mode on both Android and iOS platform?

Comment: Unfourtunately server belongs to customer. And he wants Word and Excel. So this is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make files [read-only](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-a-document-read-only-5c25909c-46d9-4eb0-9d1f-d072a560e340). I'm not sure how secure is this way.
Another way is convert them to pdf. You can find more free third-party libraries to open pdf files than expensive office files opener libraries.

Comment: Thanks, it was quite easy to persuade the customer to send files in read-only mode :)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise Syncfusion library to show the excel and words as readonly directly in your app.

[Excel](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio)

[Words](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio)